# Why would spark app freeze when requesting new executors?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

New to Spark & Yarn.  I'm running a spark app on Yarn (cloudera).  Everything works fine, but if I attempt to cache an RDD then the job freezes halfway through processing.

The RDD is taking 3GB.  I'm trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this issue.  Clearly there must be a resource contention...

```
16/05/17 19:49:41 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 16 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 72)
16/05/17 19:49:42 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 32 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 104)
16/05/17 19:49:43 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 64 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 168)
16/05/17 19:49:44 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 128 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 296)
16/05/17 19:49:45 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 172 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 468)
```

...and it just hangs there...

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without the code. But, I'd guess that the program just hasn't had time to run the caching step. You clearly have dynamic allocation on, which allows the driver node to add more executors when they are needed. And 468 executors must be the maximum given your cluster. Following the progress of your application in the application monitor may be useful (http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/operation_spark_applications.html)